# Adding a css class to a mat-select item

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my Angular application, the user can 'strikethrough' a line in a table full of text inputs.

I show this with a text-decoration: line-through css class.

How can I add the text-decoration: line-through css class for a mat-select item?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you handle the user's choice to do a strike-through on a cell, but if you have some trigger/event that you listen to (like click), you can either use a ngClass or change cell's style by accessing the DOM.

1. If you want to use ngClass, and you dynamically build the table content, you might need to build an array of objects, containing cells' IDs (or some other unique property that each cell has) and keys for strike-through status, like: `cellsStatus = [ {id: 1, struck: false}, {id: 2, struck: false} ]`. Then, in a method handling the strike-through event you take the id of a cell in question and change its `struck` value to `!struck`. In your dynamically build table, you'll have something like `[ngClass]="cellsStatus[index].struck? 'cssClassWithLine' : 'cssClassWithoutLine'"` that will use one or the other cssClass depending on the value of cellsStatus[index].struck. Handling `cellsStatus[index]` here depends on the way you structured the table, and it might be more complex - would help to see the code in your template and ts that handles the table contents.
2. If you want to access the DOM elements and change style, you - again - need ID of the cells, although in this case you won't need another var (like cellsStatus array). If you have IDs for cells, in the mentioned handler method for strike-through action, you can do:

   ```
   let element = document.getElementById(id);
   if(element.style.textDecoration == 'line-through')
       element.style.textDecoration = 'none';
   else element.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
   ```

Finally, it all depends on the structure of your table and how you get the data. If you share all the relevant code, we can work out the details :)